# how to initialize static class at service level in wcf

Tags: wcf, singleton

I have singleton Log framework, can you suggest how to initialize this at service level. I have to attach event handlers as part of initialization.

When I had initialized in Service class it is getting executed(handlers added) for each client call and therefore log table getting updated with multiple times with same records. Thanks..

Comment: Off the top of my head, it seems like the simplest thing would be to check if the event handlers are already attached before adding handlers. Since the Log framework is already a singleton, a simple bool module variable should do it if you don't want to muck with detecting existing handlers.

Comment: @SixtoSaez - Thanks, I have thought to this if I don't have any other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control how a service instance gets initialized, you'll need to implement a custom service host. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx) should give a good start. The idea is to put the Log framework initialization in the service host so it only occurs once and then have it injected into each service instance.